# use jQuery live method on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two codes. This one works like a charm-

```
$("input:radio").on('change',showRatingSection);
```

But this one throws "Object has no method 'live'" error-

```
$("input:radio").live('change',showRatingSection);
```

Any ideas why?

If I assume that you can't call live method on `radios`, then how would I bind an event on the `radios` which will be added to my `DOM` in future? I know I can bind as soon as they get added but I am looking for an alternative to `live()` if it can't be used with `radios`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the best method!

```
$("body").delegate('input:radio','change',function(){
    //do code here
});
```

This work with AJAX, without ajax. I had the similar problem with "live" function too, but since I use this anywhere, I have no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, it's called [**Event Delegation**](https://api.jquery.com/on/): elements that are generated dynamically in the DOM you can fire events using the syntax following

```
$(document.body).on('click', "input:radio", showRatingSection);
```

and `.live()` has been deprecated since 1.7 version of `jQuery`

`document.body` refers to the closest parent element in the DOM,

Answer (score 1):

Delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('change', "input:radio", showRatingSection);
```

**"Object has no method 'live'"**
Yes because in the latest jQuery versions live has been removed.

**I am looking for an alternative to live()**
Yes you have an alertnative to this as suggested in this answer and others, with use of `.on()` it has a special syntax for it.

```
$(document).on('event', "selector", function);
```

---

#### Note:

Delegating to `$(document)` is very costly *(in terms of performance)* so you should always  try to delegate to the closest static parent *(Which was available at the doc ready)*.

Also there is a point if you are delegating to the closest static parent you should put that event inside `doc ready` block but if you are delegating to `$(document)` then there is no need to put it in doc ready block.